# Tell Apache whether or not to execute PHP on requests

Tags: javascript, php, apache, .htaccess

I am using PHP with Apache and wonder if there is a way to indicate from the client side that the requested PHP file shouldn't be executed/parsed. By standard, I want all PHP files to be executed when requested, but I want a way to indicate from the client side that the file should not be executed.

A nice solution would be to supply an extra header in the request using JavaScript and then write some code in a `.htaccess` file to check if the header is present, and if it is tell apache to not execute the file and just serve it as text.

Using GET parameters or something else would also be okay.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Have a look at [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). You could rewrite the request to some sendsource.php script.

Comment: Rather than allow the client to choose which files it wants the server to parse, why not decide on the server side which files unparsed output should be an option for? That way you can be a lot more certain that sensitive data won't leak.

Comment: @LucasKrupinski All files should be possible to parse, and preferably by default. For files in some directories I want sending source to be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> supply an extra header in the request [using JavaScript] and then write some code in a .htaccess file to check if the header is present

You could get Apache to check for this (secret) header and internally rewrite the request to a `viewAsSource.php`-type file that then reads the `REQUEST_URI` (or a passed query string parameter) and returns the file source instead. Similar to @LucasKrupinski suggestion, except you don't need to include anything in the PHP file itself.

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block direct access to any file in the /tools directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^tools/ - [F]

# Display PHP source...
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Action} ^display-source$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.+\.php)$ tools/display-source.php?url=$1 [L]
```

For all `.php` requests this checks for the `X-Action` HTTP request header having a value of "display-source" and that the requested file exists. If these conditions are met then the request is internally written to a `/tools/display-source.php` script, passing the URL in the `url` parameter. You could instead check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal, but note that this also includes any query string that is passed on the request.

Then, in `display-source.php`, something like:

```
<?php
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
if (isset($url)) {
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/'.$url;
    // Validate $file....
    // :
    highlight_file($file);
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly the kind of solution I want, I will see if I can get it to work

Comment: I added the `display-source.php` file and the redirection rules, but when I tried this JS code: https://jsfiddle.net/7mz4f49s/ the response was a parsed file.

Comment: That will happen if you pass an _absolute URL_ to the `highlight_file()` function (or any other similar PHP function). This must be a filesystem path.

Comment: It seems like the issue was conflicting rewrite rules in `.htaccess`. Everything works now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set a handler in the `.htaccess` file (or server configuration as well):

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

Then you need to set a symlink to the php file, on linux systems:

```
ln -s filename.php filename.phps
```

You will get syntax highlighted source when requesting `filename.phps`.

`Require all granted` is the syntax in Apache 2.4. Older versions use `Allow from all` and `Deny from none`.

Answer (score 2):

Can your PHP files have one extra line?

Line 1: `<?php include('viewAsSource.php'); ?>`

viewAsSource.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['src'])) {
    $self = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
    $lines = file($self);

    $output = '';
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $output .= nl2br(htmlspecialchars($line));
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

That way, if they request "sample.php" they get the parsed version, but if they request "sample.php?src" they get the source code?